# Using joblib.Parallel on generator object without loading generator into ram

Tags: python, parallel-processing

When I try to use joblib.Parallel like the following:

```
generator = (i for i in range(10))
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in generator)
```

But with a generator with thousands of 100mb objects, it seems to load everything in the generator into memory before actually parallel processing, causing memory issues.

How can I feed a generator directly into the function so that it internally calls the `next()` method right before processing it instead of converting to list?

Thanks,
Jack